# Can I tell if an iOS device receives a Push Notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to count the number of devices that receive a Push Notificaiton. I need to count the devices that *receive* the notification, not the number of devices that accept the notification and open the app, so `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOpetions` won't work. I can't do this on the server end, I have to do it on the client.

Is it possible to tell, from the client end, if an iOS device has *received* a Push Notificaiton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is possible from the client side. The only time an app knows a notification has been delivered is when it is running in the foreground (in that case, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called). If the app isn't running or is in the background, it has no way of knowing a notification has arrived.